# Everything alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: wine, search, find

On Windows I enjoy the super fast search tool called "[Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/)" from voidtools. Is there such an application for Ubuntu? I look up in [alternative.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/everything/) but none of them are as good as Everything. On Wine, unfortunately, Everything does not work. It runs but does not show any result.

Comment: Check `Synapse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminal `find` is one of the most powerful searchtools out there but not very user friendly like most powertools.

As an alternative **Fsearch** could be interesting for you. To install it:

first add the ppa in terminal

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-daily`

then update your repositorys

`sudo apt-get update`

and install Fsearch

`sudo apt-get install fsearch-trunk`

to remove Fsearch you can type in a terminal

`sudo apt-get remove fsearch-trunk`

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-daily`

`sudo apt-get update`

hope that helps.